# Standard Cache Org Unable not working

Tags: apex, cache

I wrote this code and am trying to confirm it is working but everything I have tried (test class, anonymous apex and even a scheduled job) so far has not allowed me to confirm the cache is actually storing the key, value pair.  I am hoping someone may know why and can explain to me what it is not working in current state.  I have seen posts about using partitions and maybe that is the answer but from what I can read I should just be able to use `Cache.Org.Put(Key, Value, Seconds)`.

```java
public class UtilityCache {

    private static final String ENV_INFO = 'EnvInfo';
    private static final Integer TTL_SECS = 600;
    
    public static String getEnvironmentName() {
        
        Set<String> keys = new Set<String>{ENV_INFO}; 
        Map<String,Boolean> result = Cache.Org.contains(keys);
        for(String key : result.keySet()) {
            System.debug('key: ' + key);
            System.debug('Is Key Present in the cache : ' +  result.get(key));
        }
        
        String envName = (String)Cache.Org.get(ENV_INFO);
        
        if (envName == null) {
            System.debug('Environment info not in cache, retrieving.');
            envName = determineEnvironment();
            Cache.Org.put(ENV_INFO, envName, TTL_SECS);
        } else {
            System.debug('Environment info retrieved from cache.');
        }
        
        System.debug('Environment: ' + envName);
        return envName;
    }
    
    private static String determineEnvironment() {
        Long startTime = DateTime.now().getTime();

        // Get current hostname
        String hostname = System.URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().getHost();
        System.debug('Gathering environment info using hostname: ' + hostname);

        String envName = 'Unknown'; // Fallback value

        try {
            // Parse hostname to get Domain instance
            System.Domain domain = DomainParser.parse(hostname);

            // Check if sandbox
            if (domain.getSandboxName() != null) {
                envName = 'Sandbox: ' + domain.getSandboxName();
                System.debug('Determined environment as sandbox. Sandbox name: ' + domain.getSandboxName());
            } else {
                envName = 'Production';
                System.debug('Determined environment as Production.');
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Exception occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
        }

        Long endTime = DateTime.now().getTime();
        System.debug('Domain parsing took ' + (endTime - startTime) + ' ms');

        return envName;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/platform_cache

Comment: Thankis identigral.  That trailhead link showed me that I needed to request trial capacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need to create a cache partition (I think you can only create a partition via the web UI) before you can use the org cache.

Using `Cache.Org` methods (`contains()`, `get()`, `put()`, etc...) requires that you set up a default partition. If you don't have any partition marked as "default", then you need to use `Cache.Org.getPartition('namespace.myPartition');` to get the appropriate partition and then call `contains()`, `get()`, `put()`, etc... on the result.

e.g.

```java
// If your org doesn't have a namespace, then the default namespace is "local"
// 'local.myPartition' and 'myPartition' will both work for getPartition()
Cache.OrgPartition part = Cache.Org.getPartition('myPartition');

// use the returned partition instead of Cache.Org for non-default partitions
part.put('foo', 'baz', 500);
system.debug(part.get('foo'));
```

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like in my developer org I needed to request trial capacity,  Once that was done I was able to get the default to work and I set up another partition and didn't make it a default and was able to get that working too.